# How to find disk size of sub-folders of same name

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, command

Suppose directory structure on Ubuntu is `/home/f1/a`, `/home/f2/a`, `/home/f3/a` and `/home/f4/a`. Suppose my objective is to know the disk size of folders `a` within each `f1`,`f2`,`f3`,`f4` (not the size of files inside these folders but the folders themselves); and to do it while I'm in `/home`.

**Question** What's the shell command I can run from `/home` to get the disk size of each folder `a`?

In my real world example I have 60 of these directories (i.e. `~/f1/a`,`~/f2/a`,...,`~/f60/a`) so a command that doesn't spam too much other information is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code works :

```
for i in `seq 1 60`
do
    du -ch ~/f$i/a | tail -n 1 | awk -F' ' {'print $1'}
done
```

Comment: `du -ch` is the right answer, but `grep total` is not the best solution.
consider `tail -n 1` instead of hard code 'total' in case of non-english local.

Comment: The above assumes a certain number of files i.e. only 60 what if there  are more then 60?

Comment: @MattGreen we can get a number with `read x` and then replace `seq 1 60` with `seq 1 $x`

Answer (score 1):

The below will give you a break down of the folder sizes and a total at the end for all the folders no matter how many there are as long as they start with f and are in /home

```
du -ch /home/f*/a/
```

Output:

```
24K     /home/mgreen/f11/a/
4.0K    /home/mgreen/f12/a/
4.0K    /home/mgreen/f61/a/
32K     total
```

I think you are looking for something more like the following though which will let u grab a total for each /a/ folder and not the total of all of them.

```
for i in $(ls /home/mgreen |grep 'f[0-9]');do for d in $(ls /home/mgreen/$i|grep "a");do printf "$i$d " ;du -sch /home/mgreen/$i/$d | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}';done ;done
```

where $i equals the top level directory f1-100 and $d equals the 'a' directory. The extra loops keeps $a assigned to a variable for printing.

Output:

```
f11/a/ 24K
f12/a/ 4.0K
f61/a/ 4.0K
```

Hope this helps.